# Ajax calling showing error "Invalid web service call"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm calling Ajax like below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        url: 'employerbrowse.aspx/GetData',
        dataType: "json",

        data: '{  "jsondata":' + jsondata + ',"key":"' + getValue('id') + '"}',
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            callback(error.responseText);

        }
    });
```

The call the doesn't goes to the web method and the error is showing like

> "Message":"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter:
>   \u0027obj\u0027."`

I cannot find out what is the problem with posting data.
The data value I'm posting with Ajax calling like

```
{
    "jsondata": {
        "pagenumber": "0",
        "sortColumn": "Name",
        "sortDirection": "asc",
        "rowPerPage": "10"
    },
    "key": "PPCrAV0oUGhy1cRdNEiN/ohdzAwD3+Qyyn5ozvhZ1B6STo0KrY+/Vggfnc4v12JS"
}
```

I cannot find any error in Ajax posting data.

The Webmethod in employerbrowse.aspx.cs page I have written like below

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
        public static JSONResponse GetData(JSONRequest obj)
        {
            JSONResponse objJSONResponse = new JSONResponse();
            SessionHelper objSessionHelper = new SessionHelper();

            return objJSONResponse;
        }
```

The JSONRequest class I have written like below

```
 public class JSONRequest
 {
        public object jsondata;
        public string key;
 }
```

If anyone has any idea please share.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you write it as `public static JSONResponse GetData(object jsondata, string key)` ?

Answer (score 0):

try to create a variable just like your class in server side, then try this ajax code:

```
//JSONRequest
    var obj = {
         jsondata : {
             pagenumber: "0",
             sortColumn: "Name",
             sortDirection: "asc",
             rowPerPage: "10"
         },
         key: "PPCrAV0oUGhy1cRdNEiN/ohdzAwD3+Qyyn5ozvhZ1B6STo0KrY+/Vggfnc4v12JS"
     };
//call server side method
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: obj,
        url: 'employerbrowse.aspx/GetData',
        success: function (data) {
            conosle.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

I removed the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` so you could pass the parameter just like the form of your class parameter in your webmethod.